# Optimization algorithms optimizing an existing system connections

Tags: optimization

i am currently working on an existing infrastructure where i have about a 1000 customer sites connected to about 5 different hubs. A customer site may connect to one or two hubs to ensure reliability but each customer site is connected to at least one hub. I want to ensure if the current system is the best or can be optimised to have better connection from customer sites to hubs, to help improve connectivity and reliability. Can you suggest good Optimisation Algorithms to look into?. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're doing some variation of the [Facility Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facility_location_problem).
This is a well-known problem, and while there are algorithms that can solve for the global optimum (Djiskra's Algorithm, or other variants of Dynamic Programming), they do not scale well (i.e. you run into the *curse of dimensionality*). You could try this, but 1000 sounds already pretty big (depends on your exact problem formulation though).

I'd recommend taking a look at this coursera mooc [Discrete Optimization](https://www.coursera.org/course/optimization). You don't have to take the whole course, but in the "Assignments" section of the video lectures, he also explains a variant of the Facility problem, some possible approaches to think about, and once you've decided which one you want to use, you can look deeper into that particular approach.